# How to know which modules a module depends on in JBoss?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

How am I supposed to know which dependencies a module need such as the PostgreSQL driver below? If I hadn't Googled it I wouldn't know that. Where am I supposed to find this information?

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgresql">    
   <resources>    
     <resource-root path="postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar"/>    
   </resources>    
   <dependencies>    
     <module name="javax.api"/>   
     <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
   </dependencies>    
</module>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Tattletale](http://tattletale.jboss.org/).

> Tattletale is an excellent tool that recursively scans your
>   application and provides detailed reports about its contents.
>   Tattletale 1.2.0.Beta2 or later contains additional support to help
>   with the new JBoss Modules class loading used in WildFly. Tattletale's
>   `"jbossas7"` report can be used to to automatically identify and specify
>   dependent module names in your application's
>   `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file.

[Use Tattletale to find application dependencies](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-UseTattletaletofindapplicationdependencies)